How can I turn this TCP async code into UDP async?
I am working on a GUI project that uses TCP and UDP async communication. I was wondering how can I turn this TCP async code into UDP broadcast async.I am using Python and I want to if I can turn this into with a few lines of code or do I have to change code entirely? Also how can i code it for broadcast, unicast and multicast async?
import asyncio
import sys
from threading import Thread

.....

        button_start_server.pressed.connect(
            lambda: self.send_message_to_event_loop("start_server")
        )
        button_send_message.pressed.connect(
            lambda: self.send_message_to_event_loop(line_edit_message.text())
        )

        # Disable the user being able to resize the window by setting a fixed size
        self.setFixedWidth(500)
        self.setFixedHeight(200)

        # Show the window
        self.show()

    def send_message_to_event_loop(self, message: str) -> None:
        """Send the `asyncio` event loop's queue a message by using the coroutine
        `put` and sending it to run on the `asyncio` event loop, putting the message
        on the queue inside the event loop. This must be done because `asyncio.Queue`
        is not threadsafe.
        """
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(
            coro=self._async_queue.put(message),
            loop=self._asyncio_event_loop,
        )


async def handle_client(
    reader: asyncio.StreamReader, writer: asyncio.StreamWriter
) -> None:
    data = await reader.read(100)
    message = data.decode()
    addr = writer.get_extra_info("peername")

    print(f"Received {message!r} from {addr!r}")

    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()


async def run_server():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(handle_client, "127.0.0.1", 8888)
    async with server:
        print("Started server")
        await server.serve_forever()


async def send_message_to_server(message: str) -> None:
    # Lazily create a new connection every time just for demonstration
    # purposes
    _, writer = await asyncio.open_connection("127.0.0.1", 8888)

    writer.write(message.encode())
    await writer.drain()

    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()


async def read_messages(queue: asyncio.Queue) -> None:
    server_task = None
    while True:
        message = await queue.get()
        match message:
            case "start_server":
                server_task = asyncio.create_task(run_server())
            case msg:
                await send_message_to_server(msg)


async def async_main(queue: asyncio.Queue):
    # Launch the tasks to sit around and listen to messages
    await asyncio.gather(read_messages(queue))


def start_asyncio_event_loop(loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop) -> None:
    """Starts the given `asyncio` loop on whatever the current thread is"""
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.set_debug(enabled=True)
    loop.run_forever()


def run_event_loop(queue: asyncio.Queue, loop: asyncio.AbstractEventLoop) -> None:
    """Runs the given `asyncio` loop on a separate thread, passing the queue to the
    event loop for any other thread to send messages to the event loop. The main
    coroutine that is launched on the event loop is `async_main`.
    """
    thread = Thread(target=start_asyncio_event_loop, args=(loop,), daemon=True)
    thread.start()

    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(async_main(queue), loop=loop)


def run_application(application: QApplication):
    application.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    async_queue = window._async_queue
    asyncio_event_loop = window._asyncio_event_loop

    run_event_loop(queue=async_queue, loop=asyncio_event_loop)
    sys.exit(run_application(application))

